# Find Duplicates across two spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets where I want to compare two different columns and highlight all the duplicates. I have code where it goes through one sheet and finds all the duplicates, but I have two separate excel files that I want to compare.

```
Sub check_dups()

    Dim cel As Variant
    Dim myrange As Range

    Set myrange = Range("a1:ad400")
    myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    For Each cel In myrange
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrange, cel) > 1 Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

How can I compare two different files instead of just comparing data in one?
Also how can I compare two specific columns, for example `C1:C400` and `AD1:AD400` instead of the entire file?

Comment: Can you give workbook names and worksheet names for the files you need to compare? If so, it will be a simple change from what you have.

Comment: C:\Users\...\Spreadsheets\File1.xls and File2.xls. They're both in the same folder. The sheet names are both Sheet1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to compare AD1:AD400 in "File1.xlsx" to C1:c400 in "File2.xlsx":

```
Sub check_dups()

Dim cel, myrange, myrange2 As Range 'Changed to range. No need to use the extra memory for variant.

Set myrange = Workbooks("File1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("ad1:ad400") 'Edited since I forgot to change this to AD1
myrange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Set myrange2 = Workbooks("File2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C400")

For Each cel In myrange
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cel, myrange2) >= 1 Then
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Note: For larger data sets, writing the first range to an array and looping through that may be faster. For the size data set given, this is not the case.

Comment: At line 10 I'm getting this:

Run-time error '1004':

Unable to get the match property of the WorksheetFunction class.

Comment: What are the data types stored in the two ranges? I just tested and this worked no problem for me.

Comment: Does this only work is integers? There were some numbers that had the value of text instead of integers, that's where I was having problems. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: I do not believe this is data type specific, but the value in the variable `cel` needs to match the data type of that value in `myrange2`.